# Generating liquibase xml file from current database

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I have tried to create liquibase XML existing from MySQL database. My goal is to generate liquibase XML schema from MySQL database.

Any way to achieve this solution.

I have already tried with dropwizard command

```
java -jar myjar-4.1.0.jar --changeLogFile="generate.xml" --diffTypes="data" generateChangeLog
```

but it does not work for me.

Comment: When you ran that command, what actually happened? What did you expect to happen? "Does not work for me" is not a very detailed description of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying so many time finally I got my solution.

Follow following steps to generate migration from existing MySQL database.
Add initial migrations.xml into the project with below lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <databaseChangeLog
            xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
             http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">
    </databaseChangeLog>
```

Run: above migration with "db migrate" for dropwizard,  it'll create databaseChangeLog and databaseChangeLogLock tables into Database.

Run Following command as per requirement.

Command Syntax :

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --classpath=[path to db driver jar] --changeLogFile=[Path to above migration.xml]  --url=[Database URL] --username=[Username] --password=[Password] [command parameters]
```

U can refer this [link](http://%20http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html) or [link](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/ant/) for above common parameter

Note: 
Command require [path to DB driver jar], JDBC.jar file for this if you don't have.